# Custom aggregation functions in SQL Server vs Aggregate in Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm topically aware, but not well versed, in the ways that one can write a custom aggregation function for SQL Server in the CLR.  I am also just getting into learning LINQ and I am intrigued by the `Aggregate` function.  It seems to me that if one had access to LINQ then writing their own custom aggregate function with SQL Server is unncessary.  Is this true? If not, are there any non-fringe cases where one would need to write a custom aggregate function with SQL Server vs using the `Aggregate` method provided by LINQ?

Comment: What do you mean by "need" or "necessary"?  Anybody can write their own client-side aggregation without `SQL` aggregates, *or* CLR, *or* LINQ for that matter, its just a loop with an iterative operation in the middle.

Comment: @RBarryYoung if I become proficient using LINQ, is there any conceivable reason that I would ever need to write a custom aggregate function in SQL Server that does something .NET can't do?

Comment: Again, define "*need*". Strictly speaking, you don't *need* to even now, with or without LINQ.  But it *might* be beneficial to.

Comment: @RBarryYoung this might be a better way to put it: generally speaking, in terms of development time, continuity in programming, and overall headache reduction, if you had to write a custom aggregate function which method would you prefer?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this counts as a fringe case, but any place where it's feasible to get a feed from a database and not feasible to filter it through LINQ is a potential case.

Some I thought of:  SSRS reports, SSIS feeds to someplace else, any place where you're making business-logic decisions in a stored procedure (which you quite arguably shouldn't, but people do.)